# Is it possible to simulate signing of a document via DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on testing our application and have the need to simulate signing of a document via the API. These aren't real documents I just need to be able to set the signing the order in a specific order but I don't receive emails for recipients until the previous one has signed. So is it possible to use the DocuSign API to sign a "Sign Here" tab? Or do I have any other options?

I haven't been able to find any clear information on this topic although I fear the answer is not. Looking through DocuSign's REST API there's a couple of endpoints that suggests I might be able to do this but I'm not quite sure it's referencing what I'm looking to do. The following endpoint has a GET and PUT function but not sure it's what I want.

```
{{baseUrl}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients/{{recipientId}}/signature_image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the DocuSign API does not have a functionality for 'robo-signing'.

If the goal is to check routing order, you could change a Signer to a Carbon Copy recipient: CC roles are immediately completed.

For reference, the `signature_image` API calls allow you to view or change a user's adopted signatures. They shouldn't be used to apply a signature to a document.